# show.bs.collapse event not firing in angular component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, nav

So I have a custom navbar toggler effect to show when the hamburger is clicked.. but annoyingly it doesnt work an angular component but worked fine on simple non angular websites.

This is my code which is in **home.component.ts** and is within the **ngOnInit** method.

It gets the body and elements no problem, JQuery all works, yet when I click on the hamburger the
navbarCollapse.on('show.bs.collapse) event does not fire. Is there some issue with capturing bootstrap4 events in an angular component? **show.bs.collapse** is a bootstrap event.

```
var body = $('#mainbody');
var navbar = $('.navbar');
var navbarCollapse = $('.navbar-collapse');

// Add the needed HTML elements for the plugin to work. 
// All the elements are styled in navbar-sidemnu.css.

body.append('<div class="side-menu-overlay"></div>');
var overlay = $('.side-menu-overlay');
console.log(overlay);

body.append('<div id="side-menu"></div>');
var sideMenu = $('#side-menu');

console.log(sideMenu);

sideMenu.append('<button class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>')
var sideMenuCloseBtn = sideMenu.find('.close');

sideMenu.append('<div class="contents"></div>')
var sideMenuContents = sideMenu.find('.contents');

// Configure Slide menu direction
if (navbar.hasClass('better-bootstrap-nav-left')) {
  sideMenu.addClass('side-menu-left');
}

// This event is trigerred when the user clicks the navbar toggle button.
navbarCollapse.on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  // Stop the default navbar behaviour (don't open the collapse navigation).
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked hamburger!");
  // Instead we copy the navbar contents and add them to our side menu.
  var menuContent = $(this).html();
  sideMenuContents.html(menuContent);

  // Animate the side menu into frame.
  slideIn();
});


// Hide the menu when the "x" button is clicked.

sideMenuCloseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  slideOut();
});

// Hide the menu when the overlay element is clicked.

overlay.on('click', function (e) {
  slideOut();
});

// Listen for changes in the viewport size.
// If the original navbar collapse is visible then the nav is expanded.
// Hide/Show the menu accordingly.

$(window).resize(function () {
  if (!navbarCollapse.is(":visible") && body.hasClass('side-menu-visible')) {
    sideMenu.show();
    overlay.show();
  }
  else {
    sideMenu.hide();
    overlay.hide();
  }
});

function slideIn() {
  body.addClass('overflow-hidden');
  sideMenu.show();
  setTimeout(function () {
    body.addClass('side-menu-visible');
    overlay.fadeIn();
  }, 50);
}

function slideOut() {
  body.removeClass('side-menu-visible');
  overlay.fadeOut();
  setTimeout(function () {
    sideMenu.hide();
    body.removeClass('overflow-hidden');
  }, 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by putting the js in an injectable service and using that in my component.